# SvcUtil.exe creating its own class name for service contract implementation class - WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, proxy, svcutil.exe

I've written a WCF service and hosted in IIS 6.0. When i try to create the proxy using the following command

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:MyProxy.cs /config:app.config /a http://serviceurl
```

it is creating its own class name in MyProxy.cs. Why is that?

I was trying to step in to the service for debugging and i was not able to get the breakpoint hit during debugging. Could this be because i renamed the class name which is created by the Proxy?

In the service, the class name that implements the service contract is something like `MyService`. But in the proxy file i'm getting as `MyClient`.

Why is that?

Thank you

NLV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MyClient` class generated by `svcutil` and implementing the service contract should be used to invoke the service. It's just a client proxy. If you want to debug the service you should run the **service** in Debug mode and place a breakpoint there.

Comment: I understand that. I'm just asking that if a class name change in my proxy will do any harm for debugging the service?